# XSLT not working on IE 11, doesn't transform xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

Trying to render XSLT stylesheet that's coming from API, thought it's working fine on Chrome, FF except IE.

I tried using the example from w3c which works but that's calling the XML and XSLT from a file, where as mine is coming from AJAX call success response.

W3school sample [XSLT sample](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_cdcatalog)

My version is this

```
function getJson() {
 $.get(url)..
 var json2XMLResult = J2XML.json2xml_str(data);
 getResultXsl(json2XMLResult )
}

function getResultXsl(json2xml) {
    $.get(url)
        .then(function (data) {
            let resDefinition = data.Results.ResponseDisplayDefinition;
            let xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Response>' + json2xml + '</Response>';
            if (typeof DOMParser != "undefined") {
                parseXml = function (xmlStr) {
                    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
                };
            }
            else if (typeof ActiveXObject != "undefined" &&
                new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
                parseXml = function (xmlStr) {
                    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = "false";
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
                    return xmlDoc;
                };
            }

            else {
                throw new Error("No XML parser found");
            }

            displayResult(xmlString, resDefinition);
        })
}
```

Displaying XSLT in the html, the `alert()` below does show whether you're trying to render it on Chrome or IE,

```
function displayResult(xmlStrToConvert, xslStrToConvert) {
    var xmlConverted = parseXml(xmlStrToConvert);
    var xslConverted = parseXml(xslStrToConvert);
    if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {
        alert('It is IE but not showing anything');
        var ex = xmlConverted.transformNode(xslConverted)
        $('#xmlJson').append(ex);
    } else {
        alert('its not IE');
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslConverted);
        var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlConverted, document);
        $('#xmlJson').append(resultDocument);

    }
}
```

Also tried `var ex= xmlConverted.transformToFragment(xslConverted, document);`

Can someone point-out what's wrong with this? Also couldn't open dev tool on IE11 which is harder to debug, but I can tell its something wrong with my code above.

***Edit*** 
Ajax Call with `beforeSend` can someone check if the below code is fine, though the `transformNode()` is returning `Object doesn't support property or method 'transformNode'` or `XSLTProcessor()` not defined

```
function transformXML(json2xml) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: window.parent.__env.apiManagement + 'Preview/TypeDefinition?objectName=' + apiObjectResponse,
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        else {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        try { xhr.responseType = "msxml-document"; } catch (err) { }
    },
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        var parseXml = new DOMParser();
        var xslStylesheet = parseXml.parseFromString(data.Results.ResponseDisplayDefinition, "text/xml");
        var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Response>' + json2xml + '</Response>';
        var convertedXML = parseXml.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

        // // cross-browser logic omitted for simplicity
        if(window.ActiveXObject || xhr.responseType == "msxml-document") {
            var ex = convertedXML.transformNode(xslStylesheet);
            console.log('>>> ', convertedXML)
            alert(xmlString)
            $('#xmlJson').append(ex);
        }
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
            var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);
            var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(convertedXML, document);
            $('#xmlJson').append(resultDocument);
        }

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Have you checked the console for an error pointing to the issue?

Comment: You can not open the dev tools? Open it before you open the page?

Comment: couldn't open console on IE for some reason, it keep crashing :/ but when I tried the example from W3C it works perfectly.

Comment: @epascarello Yeah it keep crashing, I tried that too IE just crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 11 supports DOMParser but using it builds an IE XML DOM document which does not have any support for XSLT. So you at least need to change the order of checks, if you are coding for IE and want to do XSLT then make sure you create an MSXML DOM document using ActiveXObject, then you can use `transformNode` on it.

As you seem to want to parse XML and XSLT from strings and then use client-side XSLT transformation I would suggest to use an approach like in https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2016/test2016123001.html, which does

```
  function parseXmlStringForTransformation(xml) {
      try {
          var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
          doc.loadXML(xml);
          return doc;
      }
      catch (e) {
          var domParser = new DOMParser();
          var doc = domParser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
          return doc;
     }
  }
```

and then uses XSLTProcessor where supported or the corresponding MSXML 6 ActiveX XSLT API to run the transformation:

```
  function transform(xmlDoc, xslDoc, xsltParams, targetElement) {
      if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined') {
        var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
        proc.importStylesheet(xslDoc);

        for (var prop in xsltParams) {
          proc.setParameter(null, prop, xsltParams[prop]);
        }

        var resultFrag = proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, targetElement.ownerDocument);

        targetElement.textContent = '';
        targetElement.appendChild(resultFrag);
      }
      else {
          var template = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XslTemplate.6.0');
          template.stylesheet = xslDoc;
          var proc = template.createProcessor();

          for (var prop in xsltParams) {
            proc.addParameter(prop, xsltParams[prop]);
          }

          proc.input = xmlDoc;

          proc.transform();

          var resultHTML = proc.output;

          targetElement.innerHTML = resultHTML;
      }
  }
```

You can then use that as in

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    transform(
        parseXmlStringForTransformation('<root>...<\/root>'),
        parseXmlStringForTransformation('<xsl:stylesheet ...>...<\/xsl:stylesheet>'),
        { }, // empty parameter object if you don't want to pass parameters from Javascript to XSLT
        document.getElementById('d1')  // target element in your HTML to insert the transformation result into
    );
  })
```

Comment: Yeah I meant w3school not C, my bad. But otherwise the code above is right? Just the `if()` that need to be right?

Comment: The example on W3school is using `xhttp` does `$.get()` have access to `xhttp.responseType`?

Comment: There are other issues like `xmlDoc.async` being a boolean property you should set to a boolean Javascript value if you want to set it and not to a string but as far as I remember as long as you use `loadXML` to parse a string the parsing is synchronous anyway. I can't tell whether that mix of JQuery with browser DOM/APIs makes any sense, I don't use JQuery. If you want to load the XML and XSLT over HTTP see http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016081501.html for an example that works with IE 11, Edge, Chrome, Mozilla.

Comment: But my xml and xslt are not coming from a file, my xml is coming from the API which is a JSON and I convert it to XML, my XSLT is also coming from the back-end which I call. The example above how can I use my xml&xslt which aren't file base.

Comment: I've edited my question, can you check it if possible if its correct. Note: I'm not loading xml/xsl files.

Comment: Just saw your edit and tried it and it worked perfectly. Yeah needed to parse it as xsl/xml returns as `String` unless XSLT can transform `String`